# HDFS Corrupt Files after Spark Hana Connector Install

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, ambari

since the installation of the SAP HANA Spark Connector, I expirience major troubles with our Cloud based Hadoop Cluster (HDP 2.3). Corrupted Blocks lead the NameNode to alway turn on Safemode.

hdfs fsck gives me the following informations:

```
[User@node-aa71f18bd ~]$ FSCK started by hdfs (auth:SIMPLE) from /10.97.20.236 for path / at Wed Nov 18 1                 3:49:31 UTC 2015
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
[User@node-aa71f18bd ~]$ .
-bash: .: filename argument required
.: usage: . filename [arguments]
[User@node-aa71f18bd ~]$ /amshbase/data/default/METRIC_AGGREGATE/.tabledesc/.tableinfo.0000000001: CORRUP                 T blockpool BP-1656641573-10.97.31.53-1446206026510 block blk_1073741852
-bash: /amshbase/data/default/METRIC_AGGREGATE/.tabledesc/.tableinfo.0000000001:: No such file or directory
[User@node-aa71f18bd ~]$
[User@node-aa71f18bd ~]$ /amshbase/data/default/METRIC_AGGREGATE/.tabledesc/.tableinfo.0000000001: MISSIN                 G 1 blocks of total size 911 B....................
-bash: /amshbase/data/default/METRIC_AGGREGATE/.tabledesc/.tableinfo.0000000001:: No such file or directory
[User@node-aa71f18bd ~]$ /amshbase/data/default/METRIC_AGGREGATE_DAILY/6e87af3b3351ba6f55092465a59053b8/.                 regioninfo: CORRUPT blockpool BP-1656641573-10.97.31.53-1446206026510 block blk_                 1073741857
-bash: /amshbase/data/default/METRIC_AGGREGATE_DAILY/6e87af3b3351ba6f55092465a59053b8/.: No such file or directory
[User@node-aa71f18bd ~]$
[User@node-aa71f18bd ~]$ /amshbase/data/default/METRIC_AGGREGATE_DAILY/6e87af3b3351ba6f55092465a59053b8/.                 regioninfo: MISSING 1 blocks of total size 57 B.................................                 ........
-bash: /amshbase/data/default/METRIC_AGGREGATE_DAILY/6e87af3b3351ba6f55092465a59053b8/.: No such file or directory
[User@node-aa71f18bd ~]$ /amshbase/data/default/SYSTEM.CATALOG/167feb5a405a77b26fcaea5d560c84b1/.regionin                 fo: CORRUPT blockpool BP-1656641573-10.97.31.53-1446206026510 block blk_10737418                 37
-bash: /amshbase/data/default/SYSTEM.CATALOG/167feb5a405a77b26fcaea5d560c84b1/.regionin: No such file or directory
[User@node-aa71f18bd ~]$
[User@node-aa71f18bd ~]$ /amshbase/data/default/SYSTEM.CATALOG/167feb5a405a77b26fcaea5d560c84b1/.regionin                 fo: MISSING 1 blocks of total size 49 B..
-bash: /amshbase/data/default/SYSTEM.CATALOG/167feb5a405a77b26fcaea5d560c84b1/.regionin: No such file or directory
[User@node-aa71f18bd ~]$ /amshbase/data/default/SYSTEM.CATALOG/167feb5a405a77b26fcaea5d560c84b1/0/b6a59d0                 53baa46b1875e6506d01ebd12: CORRUPT blockpool BP-1656641573-10.97.31.53-144620602                 6510 block blk_1073741922
-bash: /amshbase/data/default/SYSTEM.CATALOG/167feb5a405a77b26fcaea5d560c84b1/0/b6a59d0: No such file or directory
[User@node-aa71f18bd ~]$
[User@node-aa71f18bd ~]$ /amshbase/data/default/SYSTEM.CATALOG/167feb5a405a77b26fcaea5d560c84b1/0/b6a59d0                 53baa46b1875e6506d01ebd12: MISSING 1 blocks of total size 40519 B........
-bash: /amshbase/data/default/SYSTEM.CATALOG/167feb5a405a77b26fcaea5d560c84b1/0/b6a59d0: No such file or directory
[User@node-aa71f18bd ~]$ /amshbase/data/default/SYSTEM.STATS/.tabledesc/.tableinfo.0000000001: CORRUPT bl                 ockpool BP-1656641573-10.97.31.53-1446206026510 block blk_1073741842
-bash: /amshbase/data/default/SYSTEM.STATS/.tabledesc/.tableinfo.0000000001:: No such file or directory
[User@node-aa71f18bd ~]$
[User@node-aa71f18bd ~]$ /amshbase/data/default/SYSTEM.STATS/.tabledesc/.tableinfo.0000000001: MISSING 1                  blocks of total size 838 B......................
-bash: /amshbase/data/default/SYSTEM.STATS/.tabledesc/.tableinfo.0000000001:: No such file or directory
[User@node-aa71f18bd ~]$ /app-logs/ambari-qa/logs/application_1446206072803_0002/node-a09295f36.Domain                 _45454: CORRUPT blockpool BP-1656641573-10.97.31.53-1446206026510 block blk_1073                 741887
-bash: /app-logs/ambari-qa/logs/application_1446206072803_0002/node-a09295f36.Domain: No such file or directory
[User@node-aa71f18bd ~]$
[User@node-aa71f18bd ~]$ /app-logs/ambari-qa/logs/application_1446206072803_0002/node-a09295f36.Domain                 _45454: MISSING 1 blocks of total size 11733 B......
-bash: /app-logs/ambari-qa/logs/application_1446206072803_0002/node-a09295f36.Domain: No such file or directory
[User@node-aa71f18bd ~]$ /app-logs/ambari-qa/logs/application_1446206072803_0005/node-60c160a97.Domain                 _45454: CORRUPT blockpool BP-1656641573-10.97.31.53-1446206026510 block blk_1073                 741912
-bash: /app-logs/ambari-qa/logs/application_1446206072803_0005/node-60c160a97.Domain: No such file or directory
[User@node-aa71f18bd ~]$
[User@node-aa71f18bd ~]$ /app-logs/ambari-qa/logs/application_1446206072803_0005/node-60c160a97.Domain                 _45454: MISSING 1 blocks of total size 6691 B.......
-bash: /app-logs/ambari-qa/logs/application_1446206072803_0005/node-60c160a97.Domain: No such file or directory
[User@node-aa71f18bd ~]$ .............
bash: .............: command not found...
[User@node-aa71f18bd ~]$ /hdp/apps/2.3.2.0-2950/tez/tez.tar.gz: CORRUPT blockpool BP-1656641573-10.97.31.                 53-1446206026510 block blk_1073741827
-bash: /hdp/apps/2.3.2.0-2950/tez/tez.tar.gz:: No such file or directory
[User@node-aa71f18bd ~]$
[User@node-aa71f18bd ~]$ /hdp/apps/2.3.2.0-2950/tez/tez.tar.gz: MISSING 1 blocks of total size 56926645 B                 ..................................
-bash: /hdp/apps/2.3.2.0-2950/tez/tez.tar.gz:: No such file or directory
[User@node-aa71f18bd ~]$ /user/ambari-qa/DistributedShell/application_1446206072803_0004/AppMaster.jar: C                 ORRUPT blockpool BP-1656641573-10.97.31.53-1446206026510 block blk_1073741897
-bash: /user/ambari-qa/DistributedShell/application_1446206072803_0004/AppMaster.jar:: No such file or directory
[User@node-aa71f18bd ~]$
[User@node-aa71f18bd ~]$ /user/ambari-qa/DistributedShell/application_1446206072803_0004/AppMaster.jar: M                 ISSING 1 blocks of total size 46057 B...........Status: CORRUPT
-bash: /user/ambari-qa/DistributedShell/application_1446206072803_0004/AppMaster.jar:: No such file or directory
[User@node-aa71f18bd ~]$  Total size:    2217611677 B (Total open files size: 166 B)
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
[User@node-aa71f18bd ~]$  Total dirs:    188
bash: Total: command not found...
[User@node-aa71f18bd ~]$  Total files:   156
bash: Total: command not found...
[User@node-aa71f18bd ~]$  Total symlinks:                0 (Files currently being written: 4)
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
[User@node-aa71f18bd ~]$  Total blocks (validated):      133 (avg. block size 16673772 B) (Total open fil                 e blocks (not validated): 4)
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
[User@node-aa71f18bd ~]$   ********************************
bash: ********************************: command not found...
[User@node-aa71f18bd ~]$   UNDER MIN REPL'D BLOCKS:      9 (6.766917 %)
>   dfs.namenode.replication.min: 1
>   CORRUPT FILES:        9
>   MISSING BLOCKS:       9
>   MISSING SIZE:         57033500 B
>   CORRUPT BLOCKS:       9
>   ********************************
>  Minimally replicated blocks:   124 (93.233086 %)
>  Over-replicated blocks:        0 (0.0 %)
>  Under-replicated blocks:       0 (0.0 %)
>  Mis-replicated blocks:         0 (0.0 %)
>  Default replication factor:    3
>  Average block replication:     2.7969925
>  Corrupt blocks:                9
>  Missing replicas:              0 (0.0 %)
>  Number of data-nodes:          3
>  Number of racks:               1
> FSCK ended at Wed Nov 18 13:49:31 UTC 2015 in 29 milliseconds
>
>
> The filesystem under path '/' is CORRUPT
```

Problem is, there are no "Data" on the cluster. Some of the parts seem to be logfiles - but of uthers i'm not sure, if I would delete required system files (e.g. AppMaster.jar). How can I recover at least the important files, without setting up the whole system again?

Thank you for your help,
Sascha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Chef script that was used to set up the cluster nodes in an cloud environment set the VM’s storage as primary storage volume for DataNodes. So hdfs ran out of storage. But only in one of the three attached volumes. The issues had nothing to do with the Hana Spark Connector in particular any other files would have caused the same issue sooner or later.